# Fazer soma de todos os dados pesquisados

Tags: c#, html

Estou fazendo um relatório, consegui efetuar a ele me trazer os dados de datas especificas, mas estou precisando agora que ele me traga a soma de tudo que foi selecionado, eu fiz uma tentativa mas não trás a soma de tudo, só algumas coisas foram somadas.

Minha View:

**Relatório Venda por Pedido/Período De: @ViewBag.dataInicio á @ViewBag.dataFinal**

```
                <tr>

                    <th>N° Carro </th>
                    <th>Quant. </th>
                    <th>Km </th>
                    <th>Valor Unitário </th>
                    <th>Sub Total </th>
                    <th>Data Abastecimento </th>
                </tr>
                        @{foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                foreach(var iten in Model)
                                {
                             <tr>
                             <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.NumCarro.NCarro) </td>
                             <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.Litro) </td>
                             <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.Km) </td>
                             <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.VlrUnit) </td>
                             <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.TotalGasto) </td>
                             <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.DtAbastecido) </td>
                             </tr>
                            }
                                }
                        }
```

Ele ta fazendo a soma direto na view, não sei se tem como aplicar pelo controller, na minha view o que me retorna é essa soma.

Assim que retorna a soma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que o problema está no loop acima...todos os dados estão repetidos

Comment: coloquei mais coisas antes da view

Comment: puts....tem 2 foreach aninhados aí...

Comment: só tirar o primeiro foreach...a soma está correta

Comment: poderia coloca a resposta somente eu para dar o certo lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no seu loop que repete os dados. A soma está correta.
Basta remover o primeiro foreach

```
@{

//Remover esse -> foreach (var item in Model) 

foreach(var iten in Model)
{
    <tr>
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.NumCarro.NCarro) </td>
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.Litro) </td>
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.Km) </td>
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.VlrUnit) </td>
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.TotalGasto) </td>
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iten.DtAbastecido) </td>
    </tr>
}

}
```